# How to use explode function in PHP without delimeters

Tags: php

i have one variable like this :

```
$variable = "0904201600000123";
```

i want to make the first 8 digits become like this :

```
2016-04-09
```

have tried to use this code :

```
<?php
$name  = "$variable;
$explode = explode("", $name);
echo $explode[0];
echo "-";
echo $explode[1];
echo "-";
echo $explode[2];
?>
```

but it does not work.

May you know where is the problem?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: convert it to date first `strtotime('Y-m-d', $name)`... then explode using `-`...

Comment: `explode()` requires a delimiter to break apart the string. Your original string doesn't have a character you are breaking it apart by. If you can be sure your string will always have 2 characters for both the day and month, and 4 characters for the year, you should look at using `substr()`

Comment: You asked the same question already 2 times: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36539188/3933332 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/36539109/3933332

Comment: explode does not work that way, you need to provide a delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a variable as you can access an array, if you were to echo:

```
$string = "test";
echo $string[0];
```

It would echo `t`, and onwards.

You could concat the string and make a new variable like:

```
$v = "0904201600000123";
$date = $v[0].$v[1].'-'.$v[2].$v[3].'-'.$v[4].$v[5].$v[6].$v[7];
echo $date;
```

I tested it on my local machine and it worked

**Note**: If you want to use the method using the `explode` function as I saw you did earlier, you could use the `str_split` function which will instead make the result an array.

Comment: I did just realise he wanted the `explode` function, but it's not possible without a delimiter so that's how you'll have to do it.

Comment: `substr()` would be cleaner IMHO

Comment: have tried this code and it is working. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Not a problem @AnindyaPutri - Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Substr() can break a string in parts.

```
$FirtsPart = Substr($variable, 0, 8);
$SecondPart = Substr($variable, 8, 8);

$FirstPart = strtotime('Y-m-d', $FirstPart);

 $variable = $FirstPart . $SecondPart;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$variable = "0904201600000123";`

Note: The date format of $variable didnt understand. If its not a standard format, considering it as a string and separate using substr

**Option 1**

```
$date = substr($variable, 0, 2).'-'.substr($variable, 2, 2).'-'.substr($variable, 4, 4);
echo $date;
```

**Option 2**

```
$dd = substr($variable, 0, 2);
$mm = substr($variable, 2, 2);
$yy = substr($variable, 4, 4);
$date = $dd.'-'.$mm.'-'.$yy;
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$variable = "0904201600000123";

preg_match("/([0-9]){2}([0-9]){2}([0-9]){4}/", $variable, $datematches);

$newdate = $datematches[3] . "-" . $datematches[2] . "-" . $datematches[1];
```

Chances are I've more than likely massively over complicated that. Not tested but should do the trick.

Comment: @jek fixed. Forgot a period after a quote Mark.

Comment: Yeah I realised :) Thanks